# how to get one category from a column into another column, in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidy

I am trying too add one category from a column into another column but keep it as a category. here is a sample of a data:

```
structure(list(id = c("117dbbbf15", "117dbbbf15", "117dbbbf15", 
"117dbbbf15", "117dbbbf15", "117dbbbf15", "117dbbbf15", "117dbbbf15", 
"117dbbbf15", "117dbbbf15"), covid_tested = c("positive", "positive", 
"positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", 
"positive", "positive"), chills = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), cough = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), diarrhoea = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), fatigue = c("Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"
), headache = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No"), loss_smell_taste = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), muscle_ache = c("No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), nasal_congestion = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), nausea_vomiting = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), shortness_breath = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), sore_throat = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), sputum = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), temperature = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), loss_appetite = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), chest_pain = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), comorbidities = c("itchy_eyes", 
"joint_pain", "asthma", "diabetes_type_one", "diabetes_type_two", 
"obesity", "hypertension", "heart_disease", "lung_condition", 
"liver_disease"), bolean = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("healthy", "Yes"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

As you can see, the bolean column has a healthy category which I want to bring it as a category into comorbidities. Is there a way to do this with in R, preferable with tidyverse?

Comment: For example, the first six rows of the `comorbidities` column for your desired output are "healthy, healthy, healthy, healthy, healthy, obesity". Is that so?

Comment: yes, it is true. This is what I want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(
    b = as.character(bolean), 
    unhealthy = b != "healthy", 
    comorbidities = replace(b, unhealthy, comorbidities[unhealthy]), 
    b = NULL, unhealthy = NULL
  )
```

Comment: thank you. It worked. Is just that I am confused what the last three lines do?

Comment: `unhealthy = b != "healthy"` creates a temporary logical column `unhealthy`, FALSE for "healthy" and TRUE for other categories. `comorbidities = replace(...)` replaces the values in `b` with values in `comorbidities`, but only do so at positions indexed by TRUE in `unhealthy`. `b = NULL, unhealthy = NULL` removes temporary columns. @GaB

Answer (score 1):

I would use a case_when() in dplyr for this. I've created a new column called comorbidities2 to show the difference but it could be overwritten (replace comorbidites2 with comorbidities):

```
df %>% 
mutate(comorbidities2 = case_when(bolean == "healthy" ~ "healthy",
                                TRUE ~ comorbidities))
```

Comment: That was really nice as well.